# what is buffer view or buffer listner in cooja simulator in contiki?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, contiki

In instant contiki image of contiki, there is a cooja simulator.
I tried to simulate the hello world and other udp examples in cooja.
The cooja has some tool like buffer view, i.e. buffer listener window.
what is that buffer listener? It shows some buffer values but I dont know which buffer it shows?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The Cooja buffer listener will show the packetbuffer (packetbuf) which is where Contiki keeps the data to send (before pushing it to the radio or unloading into a queuebuffer) or it has recently received (read out of the radio). Be aware that the contents of this buffer will change up until just before the transmission - headers will be created (such as the 802.15.4 MAC header) to form a correct 802.15.4 frame etc.

You can set the buffer listener to any arbitrary other buffer of your liking, just provide it with the symbol (name).